# Search specific keyword MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, search, keyword

What's the best way to find a specific keyword?

I combine php and the mysql LIKE '%xxxxx%' function to search articles. When I try to search a keyword for example 'HP' I get al the results containing this keyword, so an article whichs has 'PHP' in it also appears.

What's the best way to avoid this or does anybody have a workaround, method for this? I've tried al the other MySQL operators but no luck so far. Through REGEXP my search results were getting much better but I got still things in it that didn't belong there.

Comment: What kind of regex do you use? maybe we can help adjusting it to your needs ?

Comment: Using regular expressions would be quite expensive especially if you want to scale the application. I suggest that you look at using full text search. There are operators that makes MySQL match only "HP" instead of including "PHP".

Answer (score 0):

[mySQL fulltext search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) may be for you, however that has some limitations too - most importantly, a 3-character minimum for keywords. So you couldn't search for "HP" without changing mySQL's server configuration to lower the minimum.

Comment: And what about if I need only Java, and no Javascript?